# How not to refer to dataset all the time

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am probably doing a lot of stuff very inefficiently! And so I hope you can help me grow!

Specifically:

If I have a dataset (df) called r1420 with a ton of variables (columns). lets name these columns "a", "b", "c" ... and so on.

If I want a new variable (x) that is a*b I can do the following:

```
r1420$x <- r1420$a*r1420$b
```

But is there a way to skip writing the "r1420" all the time? Something like:

```
r1420 %>%
    x=a*b
```

-- The above doesnt work.

I hope you can help me!

Best regards

Comment: `r1420 %>% mutate(x=a*b)`